# Where are the Windows 10 Stock Apps located?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm wondering, where the Windows Stock Apps such as Settings, Mail, Clock, Calculator and Calendar etc are stored. I'm not talking of Apps like Notepad, Explorer, Command Prompt or Control Panel are stored, but the ones specifically for Windows 10 and in the new Windows 10 style.

On all other apps, even explorer, you are able to visit its file location, but for apps like Settings, there isn't even a file named like that by default

So, does anyone know where these are stored? Are they stored inside a dll like many other things or so?

Comment: They are in the Windows App folder located in the C:\Program Files folder. This is a hidden folder (and probably should stay that way) but you can un-hide it in File Explorer - View - Folder Options.  My answer was disliked and deleted

Comment: They should be located in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`. You need to take ownership of the folder to view its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Apps are in *C:\Program Files\WindowsApps*. Windows Apps are a particular type of app. Not normal Windows' programs.

These are newer programs like Mail, Weather, and Calculator.

To start them you use a URL. EG to start calculator you type `calculator://`.

To list all URLs

This line in a batch file (change `%%A` to `%A` if typing) lists all of them (incl http etc).

```
@For /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%A in ('reg query HKCR /f "URL:*" /s /d ^| findstr /c:"URL:" ^| findstr /v /c:"URL: " ^| Sort') Do @Echo %%A %%B
```

When you have the protocol name append :// to it. So Weather app is `msnweather://`.

The reason to use URL as the executable name changes as its updated.

This is the list from my computer

```
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:armodelviewing 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:Available Networks Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:bingfinance 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:bingmoney 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:bingnews 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:bingsports 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:bingweather 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:calculator 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:callto 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:clientx 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:com.microsoft.3dviewer 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:com.microsoft.builder3d 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:com.microsoft.print3d 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:Devices Flow Connectable Devices Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:Devices Flow Display Topology Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:dlna-playsingle Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:feedback-hub 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:File Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:File Transfer Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:File Transfer Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:http 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:https 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:HyperText Transfer Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:HyperText Transfer Protocol with Privacy 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:insiderhub 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:LDAP Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:LDAP Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:mailto 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:MailTo Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:maps 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft-edge 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft-edge-holographic 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft.windows.camera 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft.windows.camera.multipicker 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft.windows.camera.picker 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft.windows.photos.crop 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft.windows.photos.picker 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft.windows.photos.search 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoft.windows.photos.videoedit 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoftmusic 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:microsoftvideo 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:MK Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:mms Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:mms Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-aad-brokerplugin 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-actioncenter 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-appinstaller 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-apprep 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-calculator 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-callrecording 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-chat 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-clock 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-contact-support 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-cortana 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-cortana-ainotebook 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-cxh 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-default-location 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-device-enrollment 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-drive-to 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-gamebarservices 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-gamingoverlay 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-get-started 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-getoffice 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-holographicfirstrun 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-inputapp 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-ipmessaging 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-lcrv 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-mobileplans 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-msdt 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-oobenetwork 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-paint 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-penworkspace 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-people 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-phone-companion 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-photos 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-playto-miracast 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-projection 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-quick-assist 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-retaildemo-launchbioenrollment 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-retaildemo-launchstart 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-airplanemode 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-bluetooth 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-cellular 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-emailandaccounts 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-language 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-location 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-lock 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-mobilehotspot 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-notifications 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-power 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-privacy 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-proximity 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-screenrotation 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-wifi 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-settings-workplace 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-sttoverlay 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-taskswitcher 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-unistore-email 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-walk-to 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-wcrv 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-windows-search 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-windows-store 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-windows-store2 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-wpc 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-wpdrmv 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-xbet-survey 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:ms-xbl-3d8b930f 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:msnews 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:msnfinance 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:msnmoney 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:msnnews 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:msnsports 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:msnweather 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:netflix 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:onenote 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:onenote-cmd 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:outlookaccounts 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:outlookcal 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:outlookmail 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:Play Single DLNA Item Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:read 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:RES Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:RLogin Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:sms 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:snapfish 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:tbauth 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:tel 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:Telnet Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:TN3270 Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:tripadvisor 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:twitter 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:Virtual Touchpad 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:VMware Restricted VM Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:VMware VMRC Protocol 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:windows-feedback 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:windows.tbauth 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:windowsdefender 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbls 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-arena 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-captures 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-friendfinder 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-gamehub 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-lfg 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-network 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-profile 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-settings 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-store 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xbox-tcui 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xboxgames 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xboxliveapp-1297287741 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:xboxmusic 
    (Default)    REG_SZ    URL:zune 
    @C:\WINDOWS\system32\ieframe.dll,-904    REG_SZ    URL:HyperText Transfer Protocol with Privacy 

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```